# Electric noise when using a Condenser Mic in home studio

Tags: microphone, recording, pro-tools, noise, hiss

I am setting up a condenser mic for my ProTools 8 system on the Digi 03 interface. I have a Neuman TML 103 mic running through a 25 FT Planet Waves XLR cable. When I turn on Phantom power and put the gain at about 50% the mic starts to pick up random high-hissing electrical sounds that come in and out.

I recorded it and put on SoundCloud https://soundcloud.com/fireflies-the-musical/static-noise-condenser-neuman-tlm103/s-BI5UX

The Noise comes in at 0:11, and then 0:23 and many other places. My phone was on the table about 10 feet away and I had no other electronics on me. When I got loser to the mic also, are around 1:00 there is another hiss that comes in. The only thing plugged in now is my Mac Pro, Monitor, and DiGi03, all going to the same power source, a surge protector plugged into another surge protector.

Any help on getting a clean sound is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Certain cell phone technology can cause this, it's a well documented issue, so searching on Google should provide more in-depth answers.

Turn your mobile off completely and leave outside the studio.

See if you still experience the noise.